# How to stop an event always occurring before another in InitializeComponent()? - winform C#

Tags: c#, winforms

For example, the InitializeComponent() method contains

```
this.AA.ItemCheck += new System.Windows.Forms.ItemCheckEventHandler(this.AA);
this.BB.ItemCheck += new System.Windows.Forms.ItemCheckEventHandler(this.BB);
```

When compiling this program event AA always occurs before event BB is raised, but in some cases, the reverse is necessary. Is there a way to do this in short?

Comment: you're asking a broad question with no specific problem or scenario for us to address here.  If there is a condition that might otherwise mean `this.BB` should be registered as a handler before `this.AA` then you would reflect on that condition when initializing the component; otherwise, you would have a function that unregisters the handlers and then registers them..

Comment: then also, there is a multicast delegate handler that maintains a reference to the registered handlers that you can access.  then again, if you need an ordering you could define your own multicast delegate array and event manager notions.. then again, perhaps you're defining events at the wrong level if there is such an interdependence and conditional scenario going on here... you can see where this might be a broad, discussion orientated question to be raising, huh?

Comment: If the events are set in the `InitializeComponent()` method, it's designer-generated code (right?). Each event is subscribed in a Control's initialization proc. Are these events raised while the Form itself is initializing? Then this is the order in which these controls are initialized by the designer's code (that you cannot change). You can subscribe to events in the Form's constructor (after `InitializeComponent()` has already returned), removing the events from the Form's Designer. IMO, you shouldn't rely too much on the order in which the events are raised anyway.

Comment: Hi. All of the above events were created automatically by the compiler when I select from standard events that compiler supported. This means I'm not creating new events. And now, how do I prioritize one of these events because currently, it's occurring in a way I don't know?

Comment: You cannot control when an event is raised. You can subscribe an event and get notified when it is raised. Very simple and straight forward.

Comment: Not by the compiler, by the Form's designer. If you don't like (for some reason) the order in which these events are raised when the Form initializes, remove the subscription from the designer and subscribe to the events in code (e.g., write `this.AA.ItemCheck += this.AA_OnItemCheck;` etc. in the Form's constructor, right after `InitializeComponent();`). The events you're showing are raised when you check an item in one of the controls. Write code that checks these items in the order you prefer. (As already noted, you shouldn't rely on the order in which events are raised)

Comment: oh, I'm clear. Thanks you all!.